# Java Scanner why is nextLine() in my code being skipped?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Inserting L");
    int L = kb.nextInt();   
    System.out.println("Inserting N");
    int N = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Inserting x");
    String x = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println("You inputed L,N,x");
```

Why is there no prompt for `nextLine()` in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
String x = kb.next();
```

instead of `kb.nextLine()`.

This is because `nextInt()` reads just the number, not the end of line or anything after the number. When you call `nextLine()` it reads the remainder of the same line and does not wait for input.

Ideally you should call `kb.nextLine()` the line after your code for `nextInt()` to ignore the rest of the line.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about remaining characters in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Inserting L");
    int L = kb.nextInt();   
    System.out.println("Inserting N");
    int N = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Inserting x");
    String x = kb.next();
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println("You inputed L,N,x");
```

try this one...