# nextLine() not pausing

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.util.Scanner : why my nextLine() in my code not promt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289765/java-util-scanner-why-my-nextline-in-my-code-not-promt)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner npwn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first,second,answer;
        String op;
        System.out.print("Insert first number: ");
        first = npwn.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Insert Operation ('+', '-', '*', '/')");
        op = npwn.nextLine();
        if (op.equals("+")) {
            System.out.print("Insert next number: ");
            second = npwn.nextInt();
            answer = first + second;
        } 
        else { System.out.print("Insert next number: ");
        second = npwn.nextInt(); 
        answer = first - second;

        }
        System.out.println(answer);
}
}
```

Where it says "op:nextLine();"; it doesn't pause and wait for the "nextLine" persay. It just skips and prints "Insert next number: ". Why is this?

Comment: I found another question. I had to use "next()" instead of "nexLine()". Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289765/java-util-scanner-why-my-nextline-in-my-code-not-promt?rq=1

Comment: You only need to declare `answer` before usage. Don't do premature declaration.