# why does the program skip over the name i need to be inputted

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassList {

    static final int SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String Args[]) {

        Student[] students = new Student[SIZE];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name, id;
        float gpa;

        do {

            System.out.println("Enter a Student");
            name = s.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter a ID");
            id = s.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter a GPA");
            gpa = s.nextFloat();

        } while(!name.equals("quit"));
    }
}
```

basically, what happened when you run this program is that it will run one fine, then on the 2nd iteration, it will ask for a student name. but it will just skip over where the user should input it and go onto "get ID". How do i stop that.

Comment: Consider posting code with just a *little* less white space next time. Your unnecessary open spaces make your code a bit hard to read. Remember, good code formatting is more for our benefit than for yours, but since we can give you better help if we're able to easily read and understand your code, then it's also for your benefit as well.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6289765/130224

Answer (score 3):

In the first iteration, `nextFloat()` doesn't consume any new line characters. In the second iteration, the `nextLine()` method will consume the newline characters left from the first iteration. As a result, it appears that the `nextLine()` method in the second iteration skips over user input, while it's just consuming the newline characters left from the previous iteration.

One way to fix this problem is to call `nextLine()` after `nextFloat()` to consume the leftover new line character.

Answer (score 1):

You can place

```
s.nextLine();
```

at the end of the loop to consume the newline character. Currently `Scanner.getFloat()` is passing the newline character through to your statement:

```
name = s.nextLine();
```

which is *not* blocking as it has been supplied with this character.